# WooCommerce same product for different warehouses

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have some warehouses on different locations. I want add a single product on WooCommerce with different quantities and different prices for different warehouses. customer should be able to choose desired location or nearest warehouse. Is any plugin or code for doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce product vendors may solve your problem. The user needs to select the warehouse(vendor)
https://woocommerce.com/products/product-vendors/

an alternative
https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-product-vendors/

Comment: thanks, but these plugins add only one vendor on single product. i need something different, which could add 2 or more vendors on single product and only on product page user can choose one from these vendors. thanks again !!!